# PDF is not compliant with PDF/A-1b

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I am converting pdf files to PDFA using Ghostscript in my php code:

```
exec("gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dPrinted=true -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -sOutputFile=". TMP_PATH."tmp_".$file."  ". TMP_PATH.$file);
```

But the issues are:

1. This conversion is so slow (depends on the pages count and the images in the file).
2. Not every pdf should be converted, some of them are already pdfa and don't need to be converted.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anyway to detect whereas the pdf is pdfa or not to reduce the files conversions? Because sometimes the file could contain the Adobe Pdfa Scheme and still not compliant with pdfa.

   [image]

   [image]
2. Is there any other way to convert pdf files more faster using php?

Thanks in advance.